# How to stream from mic, process and play immediately back with Tarsos

Tags: process, streaming, playback, microphone, tarsosdsp

I need to stream from mic, process sound and play it immediately back.

I thought to use Tarsos, but I can't figure out how to have Tarsos' AudioPlayer to play the result back immediately. So far I can stream from mic + process + save as .pcm file. I need to add "play back immediately" between process and save.

This is the code (method processPitch not included):

```
public void record() throws FileNotFoundException {
    PitchDetectionHandler pdh = new PitchDetectionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void handlePitch(PitchDetectionResult result, AudioEvent e) {
            final float pitchInHz = result.getPitch();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    processPitch(pitchInHz);
                    frequency.setText("" + pitchInHz);
                }
            });
        }
    };
    dispatcher = AudioDispatcherFactory.fromDefaultMicrophone(SAMPLE_RATE, 1024, 0);
    AudioProcessor p = new PitchProcessor(PitchProcessor.PitchEstimationAlgorithm.FFT_YIN, 22050, 1024, pdh);
    dispatcher.addAudioProcessor(p);
    isRecording = true;

    // Output
    filePath = "/sdcard/recording_test.pcm";
    RandomAccessFile outputFile = new RandomAccessFile(filePath, "rw");
    final TarsosDSPAudioFormat outputFormat = new TarsosDSPAudioFormat(SAMPLE_RATE, 16, 1, true, false);
    WriterProcessor writer = new WriterProcessor(outputFormat, outputFile);
    dispatcher.addAudioProcessor(writer);
    recordingThread = new Thread(dispatcher, "Audio Dispatcher)");
    recordingThread.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

-SOLVED-Very simple, indeed. Just add a new player as an AudioProcessor to the dispatcher (this is mentioned in the documentation, but I didn't find the right syntax to express it):

```
dispatcher.addAudioProcessor(new AndroidAudioPlayer(outputFormat, intSize, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
```